# Seaborns tight layout do cut the plot title

Tags: python, seaborn

In the plot the title is cut on the right side of it because I used `tight_layout()`.

[image]

Can I prevent this somehow?

Here is the MWE for that plot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('Titanic')

plot = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df, y='fare')
plot.set(title='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr')
plot.tight_layout()
plot.figure.show()
```

Comment: Add a '\n' to the string where you want it to break. It won't do that for you automatically

Comment: On a more philosophical note, try to keep your titles down to a manageable length

Comment: you can adjust that with `tight_layout()` parameters, [function_doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the pad parameter:

```
plot.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
```

Another possibility to try:

```
plot.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
```